# Different behavior of Jquery/PHP after refresh

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page that allows users to post comments via jquery's ajax.  These comments can also be edited. The problem is that after i type a comment and click "edit" the jquery is not executed (ideally a modal should popup).  When i type a comment, **refresh** and then click "edit" the jquery runs perfectly.  I have been trying to debug this myself for quite some time, but I don't see why the refresh makes the difference.

`JQUERY:`

```
//this part takes the comment and enters it into a mysql database and 
//then appends the comments div to write the new comment.  This code works.
$('#answerCommentTextarea').keypress(function(e) {
if(e.which == 13) 
{
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "")
    {
        $('#nocomment').modal('show');
    }
}
else 
{           
    var comment = $('#answerCommentTextarea').val();
    $.post('../writeanswercomment.php' , 
        {
            comment: comment , 
            user: <?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>, 
            questionid: <?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>},
            function(response)
            {               
                $('#answerCommentContainer').append(response);
                $('#answerCommentTextarea').val('');
            }
        });
}
```

This is the output of writeanswercomment.php.  This is the BAD code.  When i click the edit button here, the below Jquery does not run. Even the `preventDefault()` doesnt work because `#` appears in the url

```
echo "<div class='singleComment'>
<b>
    <a href='../profile.php?p=$user'>$name</a>
</b>".
$comment." 
<input type='hidden' value='$qid' name='hiddenComment' class='hiddenComment' />
<a href='#' style='color: orange;' class='editComment'><b>Edit</b></a>
<div class='commentBar'>Just now</div>
</div>";
```

This is the `Jquery` that works after the refresh, but does not work when the comment is entered and edited without any refresh.

```
$('.editComment').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var s_comment = $(this).prev('.hiddenComment').attr('value');
    $.post('../editcomment.php' , {comment: s_comment} , function(response)
    {
        $('#modalEditComment').val(response);
        $('#editCommentModal').modal('show');
    });         
});
```

If the comment is not entered via Jquery's ajax then it was previously entered and stored in the database.  This is the code that runs when a comment has already been entered.  (This is the GOOD code.  When i click the edit button, the above Jquery runs perfectly).

```
echo "<div class='singleComment'>
<b><a href='/profile.php?p=".$comment_user[$a]."'>".$name[$a]."</a></b>".
$comment[$a]".
<input type='hidden' value='".$comment_id[$a]."' name='hiddenComment'
class='hiddenComment'/>";
$current_time=time();
if ($_SESSION['id'] == $comment_user[$a] && $current_time - $comment_time[$a] <60)
{
    echo " <a href='#' style='color: orange;' class='editComment'><b>Edit</b></a>";
$periods = array(
            "second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
$lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
$now = time();
$difference     = $now - $comment_time[$a];
$tense         = "ago";
for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) 
    {
    $difference /= $lengths[$j];
}
$difference = round($difference);

    if($difference != 1) 
    {
    $periods[$j].= "s";
}

    echo "<div class='commentBar'>".$difference." ".$periods[$j]."ago</div>
</div>";
```

Comment: Some proper indentation would be great...

Comment: @ThiefMaster i will go back and edit the indentation.  sorry.  did i explain what my problem was?  it's kinda hard to explain because it involves a lot of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use live() to attach your keypress event.
Here, you need to attach delegated event handlers on content dynamically added to a page.
You can use live(), delegate(), or on(). But as you can see:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live(). [<sup>[source]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

So, you can use:

```
$("#answerCommentContainer").on("click", ".editComment", function(){
    //your code here
});
```

---

**Edit:**

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. [<sup>[source]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Here, you append your ajax response to this element `#answerCommentContainer`, wich is "guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached". That's why I use it to bind the click event. You can bind any element (as the document), but I usually choose the closest parent, to prevent event from bubbling when it's not needed.

Comment: did you mean answerCommentTextarea?

Comment: THAT WORKED! you are the man.  i spend 12 hours trying to do this.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try your keypress and click events using live() function.

```
$('#answerCommentTextarea').live('keypress', function(e) {
...
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
...
}
```

and

```
$('.editComment').live('click', function(e){
...
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem, give it a try)

Comment: In jQuery you should always use `e.which` - it's the normalized version of either `e.which` or `e.keyCode` of the original event.

Comment: @acute my enter function is working fine.  The problem is that after the comment is put into the database and appened into the comments div.  I can't click edit. But I can after i refresh.  I'm curious as to why this is, because the append code and the code after refresh are very similar

Comment: @ThiefMaster: as far as I know e.which doesn't work while using live('keypress'), that's why e.keyCode is used.